# Google Apps Script Web App image workaround

Tags: dom, google-apps-script

I'm using a set of workaround functions I got from another stack overflow post, but I can't seem to modify them to work for a background image:

This works:

```
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler( function(bytes){ showImage(bytes) })
      .loadImageBytes("1WH0TrUxzzzzzzzzzcqEYZnTD6zPM9");

      function showImage(bytes){
      document.getElementById("page1").src = "data:image/png;base64," + bytes; 
      }
```

but this does not:

```
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler( function(bytes){ showImage(bytes) })
      .loadImageBytes("1WH0TrUxzzzzzzzzzcqEYZnTD6zPM9");

      function showImage(bytes){
      document.getElementById("page1").style.backgroundImage= "data:image/png;base64," + bytes; 
      }
```

The server side code is:

```
function loadImageBytes(id){
console.log(id);
var bytes = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  console.log(bytes.getName());
  try{
  bytes= bytes.getBlob();
  bytes= bytes.getBytes();
  }
    catch(e){console.log(e);}
return Utilities.base64Encode(bytes);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that in your script, the value for `backgroundImage` is required to be modified. So how about this modification?

#### From:

```
document.getElementById("page1").style.backgroundImage= "data:image/png;base64," + bytes;
```

#### To:

```
document.getElementById("page1").style.backgroundImage = "url(data:image/png;base64," + bytes + ")";
```

#### Reference:

- [background-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)